# R - Multiple data points in forest plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(Mean1=c(12,15,17,14,16,18,16,14),Lower1=c(8,11,13,7,15,12,12,11),Upper1=c(16,18,21,21,17,24,20,17),Mean2=c(13,16,18,15,17,19,17,15),Lower2=c(9,12,14,8,16,13,13,12),Upper2=c(17,19,22,22,18,25,21,18))
rownames(df) <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

I can produce a forest plot with `Mean1` `Lower1` and `Upper1` from `df`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = row.names(df), x = df$Mean1)) +
     geom_point(size = 4) +
     geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = df$Upper1, xmin = df$Lower1))
```

So my question is: How can I include `Mean2` `Lower2` and `Upper2` from `df` to the plot so that both means from each observation point (rows) are represented as pairs with their respective error bars? So the output would be a similar forest plot, but with both means and error limits from each observation points displayed in pairs. I hope this makes sense.

I haven't tried anything because I simply don't know where to start.

I this possible to perform without disrupting the structure of the data frame?

Comment: The easiest solution is to reshape the dataframe to a long format, so that each error bar has a row with lower, upper, estimate and a grouping variable. Why do you need the structure intact?

Answer (score 2):

The most natural way to do it is to use `position` argument, but it needs values grouped with variable, not column names. You can add it inplace:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x= rep(rownames(df), 2),
       y= c(Mean1,Mean2),
       group=rep(c(1,2), each=nrow(df)))) +
geom_point(position=position_dodge(1))+coord_flip()
```

But more proper way is to disrupt the structure of the data frame, it will make code more cleaner:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = rownames, 
           y = Mean, 
           group=groups)) +
geom_point(size = 4, position=position_dodge(1))+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = Upper, ymin = Lower), position=position_dodge(1))+
coord_flip()
```

For this example I've made this  data.frame transformation:

```
df <- data.frame(Mean=c(df$Mean1,df$Mean2),
                 Lower=c(df$Lower1,df$Lower2),
                 Upper=c(df$Upper1,df$Upper2),
                 groups=factor(rep(c(1,2), each=nrow(df))),
                 rownames=as.character(rep(rownames(df), 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean but do you want to plot the Mean2 values on top of the forest plot? In that case you can assign the first plot a value, lets say s1 and then add the new data to it like this (maybe add diff colors):

```
s1<-ggplot(df, aes(y = row.names(df), x = df$Mean1)) +
     geom_point(size = 4) +
     geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = df$Upper1, xmin = df$Lower1))

s1 + geom_point(data=df, aes(y = row.names(df), x = df$Mean2)) + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = df$Upper2, xmin = df$Lower2))
```

Otherwise you can restructure the data and then add facet_grid(. ~ Sample) to make seperate graphs for your samples (Mean1 and Mean2)

Comment: Thank you. This is the idea I was looking for. Do you know is it possible to display those values so that the items in each pair are lined underneath each other?

Comment: You could use `y = as.numeric(row.names(df))-0.2` in the aes of the second part. But to repeat myself, why do you need the structure of the dataframe intact? It's not the best of practice.

Comment: I'm really unexperienced when it comes to R. The data I was given was composed same as the example and I initially thought I could go on without tampering it any further. I understand now it is wise to reshape it and save me the trouble of using weird data frames.

Comment: Good luck! It gets easier with practice, I promise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it without disrupting the structure of your data frame, but since your data frame is not tidy data I would recommend to change it anyway.  Then I get the following that might answer your question:

```
library(tidyr)
df$itemid <- rownames(df)
df <- gather(df, type, value, -itemid)
df <- separate(df, type, into=c("type", "grpid"), sep=-2)
df <- spread(df, type, value)
```

done in separate steps so it is easier to execute step by step to see what is happening.  Then you can plot using:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(y = paste(itemid, grpid), x = df$Mean, color = grpid)) +
     geom_point(size = 4) +
     geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = df$Upper, xmin = df$Lower))
```