# How to add OR and 95% CI as text into a forest plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-forestplot

I want to make a forest plot by subgroup, exactly as 'stupidWolf' suggests in his answer to this question in this link (if you scroll down to the last question, you would be able to see the forest plot by subgroups) [Forest plot with subgroups in GGPlot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657802/forest-plot-with-subgroups-in-ggplot2)
But I want to add the OR and the 95% CI to that plot. Does anyone have a code that can add that information into in the forest plot?

I am able to make a forest plot by sub group in a normal ggplot. That is not a problem. But I can't figure out how to add the OR and 95% CI into the forest plot. should I use something else than ggplot? I hope someone can help! I have no clue where to begin with. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean the OR and confidence interval as text?

Comment: yes, exactly! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data in the linked question, we can add the odds ratio and confidence intervals like this:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = Outcome, y = OR, ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper,
               col = group, fill = group)) + 
  geom_linerange(linewidth = 5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, lty = 2) +
  geom_point(size = 3, shape = 21, colour = "white", stroke = 0.5,
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 3.75, group = group, 
                label = paste0("OR ", round(OR, 2), ", (", round(Lower, 2), 
                               " - ", round(Upper, 2), ")")), hjust = 0,
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = barCOLS) +
  scale_color_manual(values = dotCOLS) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "(Post)operative outcomes") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Odds ratio", limits = c(0.5, 5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! But I was thinking if you knew how to add one title 'OR' above all the OR values instead of it is written on each OR value. So I tried this, but it didn't work obviously  `label = paste0(title("OR"),` and then I wrote the rest of the code

Comment: And also, how can I plot the OR text outside the plot, like on the side to the right. Because I have very long CI unfortunately, so I can't avoid the text merging with the horizontal CI lines. If I start moving the OR text by changing the `y = 3.75` position more to the right, then the text starts to disappear (half of it), because it gets pushed out of the plot. So I was thinking if I could plot it outside the plot, then it will solve the issue maybe?  
  
I'm sorry for all these extra questions. I really appreciate your time and help!