# How to add OR and 95% CI as text outside a forest plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-forestplot

I have previously asked a similar question, which was "how to add OR and CI 95% as text into a forest plot".
In that previous question, I got my codes from a third question by someone named stupidwolf.
I used his codes to get a forest plot, BUT without OR and CI as text. This is the codes I used from stupidwolf, which worked for me.

```
library('ggplot2') 

Outcome_order <- c('Outcome C', 'Outcome A', 'Outcome B', 'Outcome D')

#this is the first dataset you have
df1 <- data.frame(Outcome=c("Outcome A", "Outcome B", "Outcome C", "Outcome D"),
   OR=c(1.50, 2.60, 1.70, 1.30),
   Lower=c(1.00, 0.98, 0.60, 1.20),
   Upper=c(2.00, 3.01, 1.80, 2.20))
# add a group column
df1$group <- "X"
# create a second dataset, similar format to first
df2 <- df1
# different group
df2$group <- "Y"
# and we adjust the values a bit, so it will look different in the plot
df2[,c("OR","Lower","Upper")] <- df2[,c("OR","Lower","Upper")] +0.5

# combine the two datasets                      
df = rbind(df1,df2)
# you can do the factoring here
df$Outcome = factor (df$Outcome, level=Outcome_order)

#define colours for dots and bars
dotCOLS = c("#a6d8f0","#f9b282")
barCOLS = c("#008fd5","#de6b35")


p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Outcome, y=OR, ymin=Lower, ymax=Upper,col=group,fill=group)) + 
#specify position here
  geom_linerange(size=5,position=position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, lty=2) +
#specify position here too
  geom_point(size=3, shape=21, colour="white", stroke = 0.5,position=position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=barCOLS)+
  scale_color_manual(values=dotCOLS)+
  scale_x_discrete(name="(Post)operative outcomes") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Odds ratio", limits = c(0.5, 5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal()
```

Then I asked in my previous question, if someone could help me with adding the OR and CI as text on the forest plot, which Allan Cameron helped me with.
This almost solved my problem.

So what I did was this, as he suggested me to do and it worked for me as well:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Outcome, y = OR, ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper,
               col = group, fill = group)) + 
  geom_linerange(linewidth = 5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, lty = 2) +
  geom_point(size = 3, shape = 21, colour = "white", stroke = 0.5,
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 3.75, group = group, 
                label = paste0("OR ", round(OR, 2), ", (", round(Lower, 2), 
                               " - ", round(Upper, 2), ")")), hjust = 0,
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = barCOLS) +
  scale_color_manual(values = dotCOLS) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "(Post)operative outcomes") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Odds ratio", limits = c(0.5, 5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal()
```

And I get this forest plot

[image]

As you can see on the forest plot the OR and CI text is inside the plot area. So I have following questions that I hope someone can help me to fix:

1. How to add one title "OR" above all the OR values instead of it is written for each OR value?
2. How can I plot the OR and CI text outside the plot, like on the side to the right. Because on my real plot I have very long CI unfortunately, so I can't avoid the text merging with the horizontal CI lines. If I start moving the OR text by changing the `y = 3.75` position more to the right, then the OR and 95%CI text starts to disappear (half of it), because it gets pushed out of the plot. So I was thinking if I could plot it outside the plot, then it will solve the issue maybe? But how?

This is the link to my previous question if necessary:   [How to add OR and 95% CI as text into a forest plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75290597/how-to-add-or-and-95-ci-as-text-into-a-forest-plot)

Comment: Please consider providing your data set for this problem instead of expecting people who want to help you to comb through your previous posts to find it. I tried, but barCOLS was not in the data.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I have now added the data/codes that was used before the forest plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the patchwork package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Outcome, y = OR, ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper,
               col = group, fill = group)) + 
    geom_linerange(size = 5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 1, lty = 2) +
    geom_point(size = 3, shape = 21, colour = "white", stroke = 0.5,
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = barCOLS) +
    scale_color_manual(values = dotCOLS) +
    scale_x_discrete(name = "(Post)operative outcomes") +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Odds ratio", limits = c(0.5, 5)) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_minimal()


p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Outcome, y = 1.25, ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper)) + 
    geom_text(aes(group = group, 
                  label = paste0(round(OR, 2), ", (", round(Lower, 2), 
                                 " - ", round(Upper, 2), ")")),
              position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), color = "black") +
    labs(title  = "OR") +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_void()


p1 + p2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! But unfortunately R keeps giving me the same error when I try to run p2. I have literally written the same as you. 
But the error says: 
" Error in `ggplot_add()`: 
! can't add `e2` to a <ggplot> objekt. Did you forget to add parentheses, as in `e2()`? "

Comment: Did you load the patchwork package?

Comment: Yes, the patchwork packages is loaded

Comment: So you can run p1 and display it?  You see your original graphic without the OR?When you run the code for p2 you get the ggplot_add error? Or is it when you run p1 + p2 that you get the error?

Comment: I get that error too if I run p1 + p2 without patchwork loaded. So do double check that you have patchwork installed and run library(patchwork) to load it.

Comment: Exactly. That is the strange thing. I can run p1 and display it as you describe. I can't run the p2 without the error coming up. I haven't even run p1+p2, as p2 does not work for me in first place :/ I have double checked with the patchwork and even updated the package. Still not working.

Comment: For some reason, all of the sudden it worked! :D I didn't even change a thing. I just kept running it. Thanks a lot for your time and help!! I really appreciate it!