# Forest plot with subgroups - formatting issues

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling to format a subgroup forest plot from this [original thread for the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657802/forest-plot-with-subgroups-in-ggplot2), which I have edited for my data.

1. The odds ratio estimates are skewed to the left of the CI lines, I can't figure out how to get them centered over the line.
2. I don't want to use this theme, I would prefer just a standard black line with whiskers but can't figure out how to adjust the theme without messing up the entire plot
3. How do I get the legend to have the orange category on top ("high racial/ethnic minority") so that it matches with the order in the plot?

Here is the code I am working with:

```
df_adj=

structure(list(Variable = structure(c(5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("racial and ethnic minority (ref = White)", 
"sex male (ref=Female)", age 12 yrs (ref=10 yrs)", 
"High population  (ref= Low)", "High land use(ref = Low)", 
"High traffic (ref = Low)"), class = "factor"), 
    Model = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), levels = c("high racial/ethnic minority", 
    "Your other factor level"), class = "factor"), Odds = c(2.12, 
    0.24, 1.16, 0.56, 1.02, 0.19, 3.72, 1.58, 3.14, 1.24, 0.9, 
    0.38), CIHigh = c(0.73, 0.07, 0.36, 0.16, 0.36, 0.02, 1.38, 
    0.49, 1.24, 0.54, 0.41, 0.17), CILow = c(6.48, 0.76, 3.72, 
    1.91, 2.88, 1.07, 10.7, 5.21, 8.74, 2.86, 1.98, 0.85), CI_midpoint = c(3.605, 
    0.415, 2.04, 1.035, 1.62, 0.545, 6.04, 2.85, 4.99, 1.7, 1.195, 
    0.51)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")



#define colours for dots and 
bars
dotCOLS = c("#a6d8f0","#f9b282")

barCOLS = c("#008fd5","#de6b35")


ggplot(df_adj, aes(x = Variable, y = Odds, ymin = CILow, ymax = CIHigh, col = Model, fill = Model)) + 
geom_linerange(size = 1.0, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, lty = 1) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 2, colour = "white", stroke = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(Odds, 2), y = CIHigh + 0.2), 
            vjust = -0.5, size = 3, color = "black", family = "Times New Roman", position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Independent Variables") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Odds ratio (95% CI)", limits = c(0, 11)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = barCOLS) +
  scale_color_manual(values = dotCOLS) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", size = 9, color = "black"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", size = 9, color = "black"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", size = 9, color = "black"),
    text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", size = 10)
  )
```

Output: [image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df_adj$Model <- factor(df_adj$Model, levels = c("high racial/ethnic minority", "Your other factor level"))
p <- ggplot(df_adj, aes(x = Variable, y = Odds, ymin = CILow, ymax = CIHigh, col = Model, fill = Model)) + 
  geom_linerange(size = 1.0, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, lty = 1) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 2, colour = "white", stroke = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(Odds, 2), y = CIHigh + 0.2), 
            hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.5, size = 3, color = "black", family = "Times New Roman") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Independent Variables") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Odds ratio (95% CI)", limits = c(0, 11)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = barCOLS) +
  scale_color_manual(values = dotCOLS) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal()
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", size = 9, color = "black"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", size = 9, color = "black"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", size = 9, color = "black"),
    text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", size = 10)
  )

print(p)
```